# How to set chart bar's width?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to write a Winforms application in C#. I'm using the chart control from the regular toolbox to view data from my SQL database. As you see, the bar is very wide. Is there some property or way to make it smaller, and fixed?

[image: http://priv.hiphotos.baidu.com/album/s%3D308%3Bq%3D90/sign=131a1ec68bd4b31cf43c92bbbfed5642/d4628535e5dde711c9184673a7efce1b9c166168.jpg?psign=de6394777d1ed21b3ae15fd4ad4712a551da81cb3bdb1fb1]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I did a small example *binding three values* and set the `PixelPointWidth` of **dataPointCustomProperties**.

```
int[] liste = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };//, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBind(liste, "sampleData", "count", "Tooltip=count");
// dataPointCustomProperties
chart1.Series["Series1"]["PixelPointWidth"] = "1";
```

will result in this chart

[image: Chart bar width 1px]

Comment: This also works. chart1.Series["Series1"].SetCustomProperty("PixelPointWidth", "1");

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following Code :

```
Chart1.Series["Series1"]["PixelPointWidth"] = "15";
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the `PixelPointWidth` in the report designer as below.

1. Click on the chart series, press `F4` to show the properties.
2. Change the `PixelPointWidth` in `CustomAttributes` node.

[image: Settting PixelPointWidth]

Answer (score 1):

VB.NET version of same problem:

```vb
Dim EL As New Series
EL.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column
EL.Name = "Series name"
EL.SetCustomProperty("PixelPointWidth", "1")
EL.Points.AddXY(x, y)
Chart1.Series.Add(EL)
```

This custom property is not accessible using chart properties. If this property is uninitialized, width of the chart bar is **random!**.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).