# C# Chart issue with space between columns and font size Y axis

Tags: c#, charts

I am struggling (I am a beginner in C#) to: 1 put some space between the columns, define a size for the Y axis and display Ancillary in the label. I post my code, any help is largely appreciate.

```
        Overall.SelectCommand = ToChart1;
        Overall.Fill(ds, "TblChart1");
        chart1.DataSource = ds.Tables["TblChart1"];
        chart1.Series.Add("Series2");
        chart1.Series.Add("Series3");
        //chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "Ancillary";
        chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "Ancillary";
        //chart1.Series["Series2"].XValueMember = "NonCommodity";
        chart1.Series["Series2"].YValueMembers = "NonCommodity";
        //chart1.Series["Series3"].XValueMember = "Totale";
        chart1.Series["Series3"].YValueMembers = "Totale";
        chart1.DataBind();
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new Font("Calibri", 5);
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
        //chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 800000;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
        chart1.Series[0].LegendText = "Ancillary";
        chart1.Series[1].LegendText = "NonCommodity";
        chart1.Series[2].LegendText = "Total";
```

Comment: How it looks and how you want it to see?

Comment: Columns are without space between them, the font size of the Y axis is too big (I can define the X Axis but not the Y axis). I do not see Ancillary in the label

Comment: Size resolved with:  chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new Font("Calibri", 6); Ancillary did come up magically. Just How can put a gap between the columns?

Comment: You can control the column sizes. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525997/how-to-set-chart-bars-width) - The better, more modern code version would be `yourSeries.SetCustomProperty("PixelPointWidth","4");`